# How to search and return list with the values with a # in front of it?

Tags: python, list, input

So I'm trying to a code using python where the user inputs a certain input and in return it gives a list with just the words with a (#) in front of it.

`def labeled(): message_input=input("Enter a message or type q to end:").split() result=list(message_input) print (result)`

So far I am able to get the message the user typed and give a list as an output but I want for the user to input a message (ex: "Nice day today #running #marathon") and for python to return [running,marathon]. With this in mind too how would I take out the punctuation at the end of a word if it has it too (ex: #marathon.) output should be [marathon].

Answer (score 0):

Using `for loop` and `if-statement` we check for the word strats with `#`. created empty list `lst = []` and appended these words to the list. Removed `#` from the word by slicing string.

```
 def labeled():
        message_input = input("Enter a message or type q to end:").split()
        result = list(message_input)
        lst =[]
        for i in result:
            if '#' in i :
               lst.append(i[1:])
        print(lst)
    
    
    labeled()
```

output

```
Enter a message or type q to end: Nice day today #running #marathon"
['running', 'marathon"']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about filtering? Try this:
`[b for b in a.split() if b.startswith("#")]`

Or specifically for your solution:

```py
def labeled():
    message_input=input("Enter a message or type q to end:")
    print ([i[1::] for i in message_input.split() if i.startswith("#")])
```

So you get something like:

```sh
>>> message_input = "Nice day today #running #marathon proper #solution..."
>>> print ([i[1::] for i in list(message_input.split()) if i.startswith("#")])
['running', 'marathon', 'solution...']
```